Не импортируется tkinter ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter' в Linux
Почему у меня при импорте графического модуля tkinter:
import tkinter as tk

возникает следующая ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asl/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'


pip3 install tkinter Не пробовали?

Встречный вопрос - а вы пробовали? tkinter нет на pypi.org, его нельзя так установить.

tkinter нужно установить дополнительно, для debian-based системах через sudo apt install python3-tk

@insolor Спасибо за ответ! Теперь у меня хотя бы самом Linux работает tkinter если я работаю без venv. Но при работе в pycharm я не знаю как установить tkinter. Как можно в venv установить данную библиотеку?

@insolor У меня была версия pycharm(flatpack) я установил с официального сайта и теперь все работает! Можете ответить на вопрос что бы я его почитал нужным!

А, это другая проблема, PyCharm из flatpack похоже не видит системный python (вне папки юзера), у меня когда-то была аналогичная проблема, когда ставил Intellij IDEA - она не видела системный JDK. Сейчас через snap ставлю PyCharm и IDEA - таких проблем нет.

@А я могу ваш ответ поставить как решение?
